# mockmvc download functionality for contentType "application/octet-stream" throws FileNotFound error

Tags: java, junit, mockmvc

I am new to the mockmvc api.

I am trying to write units for my controllers and one of the method performs download. Please find the code snippet:

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download-template", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource downloadTemplate(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        logger.info("User ID: " + request.getAttribute("userId")
                + " - POST: /upload/download-template");

        String rootDir = config.getBaseFolder();
        DownloadUploadTemplateResponse res = uploadService.downloadTemplate(
                rootDir, false);

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + res.getFileName());

        return new FileSystemResource(res.getTemplateFile());

    }
```

### Unit test code:

```
@Test
    public void testDownloadTemplate(){
        DownloadResponse res = new DownloadResponse();
        String templateFile = "upload-template.xlsx";
        String fileName = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + templateFile;
        res.setFileName(fileName);
        res.setTemplateFile(templateFile);
        when(config.getBaseFolder()).thenReturn(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        when(uploadService.downloadTemplate( System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), false)).thenReturn(res);
        //File file = new File(fileName);
        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(res.getTemplateFile());
        try{
            ResultActions action = mockMvc.perform(get("/upload/download-template").contentType(APP_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE_UTF8));
            action.andExpect(header().string("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + res.getFileName()));
            action.andExpect(status().isOk());


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
    }
```

Below line throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: upload-template.xlsx (The system cannot find the file specified):
ResultActions action = mockMvc.perform(get("/upload/download-template").contentType(APP_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE_UTF8));

Please guide what additional I need to add in the httprequestbuilder to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad .. the error was clear enef to fix the issue . The problem was the file was not physically present :).
So by placing the file in the temp folder helped me resolve the issue. Feel like ahhh .